# Guide to neural network development

Tags: neural-network

I would like to implement a neural network which can track activity in a large database.

For example, if there were some errors in the db which were detected and fixed, I need some kind of methodology that would observe the db and then infer the problem and the implemented solution.

How would I approach the problem of somehow logging what was wrong and what the user did to fix the issue?

I am just exploring options here. I would like to know if there are any other approaches out there to help solve such problems. Please feel free to let me know if something is missing in the question.

Comment: This is not the use of a neural-network. Neural-networks are for processing  complex inputs into an actionable result such as converting voice to words and images to objects. Look at github or svn, even google docs can do what you are wanting.

Comment: Use a version control system such as cvs, subversion or git. If you also want to keep track of what should be done (rather than what has been done), use an issue tracking system such as mantis bug tracker or redmine.

Comment: I think I gave a very simplistic example here. To elaborate, the size of my problem is in the scale of a database (~10 GB). There are several dbs upon which people are acting to fix errors. I would like to have a system to just observe what changes are being made to a db and then infer what prompted the change.
I thought neural network might suit this scenario

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you tink a neural network would be the way to go here....

Consider some version control program like git or svn to track changes to a file.

EDIT concerning db monitoring:
Ok I understand what you want now. A fundamental problem you have to consider is this: It is easy to monitor db changes, but the system would have to understand your teams complete workflow to be able to infer the meaning of these changes. Only then can it take guesses at what problems people are tying to fix, right?